# Performing a power operation on a matrix in Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I have the following matrix m.

```
m =

 0     0     0     0
 0     1     2     3
 0     2     4     6
 0     3     6     9
```

I am trying to perform the equivalent MATLAB operation using Python.

```
new_m = w.^m
```

i.e. convert m into the follwing matrix:

```
new_m =

 1     1     1     1
 1     w^1   w^2   w^3
 1     w^2   w^4   w^6
 1     w^3   w^6   w^9
```

Currently my Python approach is the following:

```
    N=4
    w=cmath.exp(2*pi)    # Here w = 535.491655525+0j
    row=list(range(N))   # In this case row = [0, 1, 2, 3]

    #Create the matrix and perform operation on it
    m = [[0]*N for i in range(N)]
    for x in range(1,q):
        for entry in row:
            m[x][entry]=entry*r                     # <--- This gives me give me the above matrix m

    # This was my attempt to perform the new_m=w.^m operation
    for x in range(0,q):
        for entry in row:
            element=M[x][entry]
            new_m[x][entry]=w**element             # <--- This should give me the correct new_m matrix described above
```

My Python code gives me the following result:

```
[ [  1.0000e+00+0.j   1.0000e+00+0.j   1.0000e+00+0.j   1.0000e+00+0.j]
  [  1.0000e+00+0.j   5.3549e+02+0.j   2.8675e+05+0.j   1.5355e+08+0.j]
  [  1.0000e+00+0.j   2.8675e+05+0.j   8.2226e+10+0.j   2.3579e+16+0.j]
  [  1.0000e+00+0.j   1.5355e+08+0.j   2.3579e+16+0.j   3.6205e+24+0.j]]
```

But if I perform this operation in MATLAB it gives me this answer for the `new_m = w.^m` operation:

```
new_m =

   1.0e+24 *

    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    3.6205
```

I am unsure why these answers differ and where I am going wong in what I am assuming to be a mistake in my python code.
Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated!

Note:
I have also tried using the following command after my first set of for loops (using the m matrix):

```
new_m = w**m
```

But that produced the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'complex' and 'list'
```

Comment: First - if you are doing atrix work on Python, for anything but understanding how the langauge works, you should be using Numpy  http://www.numpy.org/  - The support for operations of this kind is out of the box with Numpy Arrays - and it will be around ~10000 times faster than the same operation performed with external Python for loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**: Your Python code, and output, are both correct -if you check the output, what happens i s that Matlab just presents values in which the other numbers of the matrix are printed as rounded to "0", because it uses a single exponent (e+24) for all Matrix members.

Python's output, on the other hand, correctly prints each number with its own native magnitude.  So, "2.3579e+16+0.j " is a number 10**8 times smaller than "3.6205e+24+0.j]" , and since Matlab is using the e+24 exponent for everything, it just prints 0. Internally it stores the correct values, though.

**Second**: You should be using Numpy (http://numpy.org)  - among several other features, it does offer Matrix arithmetic out of the box.

For you power operation, for example:
:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: z = np.array(range(9))

In [3]: z
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

In [4]: z.shape = (3,3)

In [5]: z
Out[5]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [10]: w = cmath.exp(2*cmath.pi)

In [11]: w
Out[11]: (535.4916555247646+0j)

In [12]: w ** z
Out[12]: 
array([[  1.00000000e+00+0.j,   5.35491656e+02+0.j,   2.86751313e+05+0.j],
       [  1.53552935e+08+0.j,   8.22263156e+10+0.j,   4.40315059e+13+0.j],
       [  2.35785040e+16+0.j,   1.26260921e+19+0.j,   6.76116697e+21+0.j]])
```

(The `In[1]:` style prompts instead of `>>>` is due to `ipython` - an enhanced Python interactive shell that is very useful)

Besides that, performing this kind o Matrix operations by using external Python for loops can be from 1000 to 10000 times slower - so, the proper use of Numpy does involve both being familiar with Python, and being familiar with Numpy way of working, which favors matrix operations being calculated in native code.

Comment: Thank you for explaining as I was getting very confused! I have heard of numpy, but as I was struggling to correctly achieve the specific matrix m format using numpy I used python loops instead. Nonetheless I will look into again and thank you for explaining!

Comment: Note that your code for filling up the initial vaues in your matrix `m` is correct, and will be needed  after the numpy matrix it is created.

Comment: Thank you, I changed m and new_m to `m=np.zeros((N, N))` and `new_m =np.zeros((N, N))` and kept the same for loops to populate the matrices. However I now get the error `TypeError: can't convert complex to float` relating to the `new_m[x][entry]=w**element ` line. Do you have idea idea why this may be happening using np instead of the way I had it in my original question?

Comment: Sorry - for the operation you should have been able to perform it at once, with `new_m = w ** m` - have you tried it? 
What happens in the code is that after the multiplaction, NP refuses to assign a complex to new_m which has float contents, as the imaginary component would get truncated. You have to create new_m with the complex type: `new_m =np.zeros((N, N), dtype=complex)`